# Is there any reason not to co-locate small spring-boot starters with autoconfigures?

Tags: spring-boot

spring-boot uses "starters" to define a set of libraries dependencies a project may include.  This maven module, a starter for Jersey, for example:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-jersey

spring-boot uses autoconfigures to instantiate and configure the classes in the starter module.  The autoconfigure for Jersey: 

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java

Is there any reason not to co-locate new 3rd party/private starters in the same module as the autoconfigures, instead of split across separate modules like the example above?

Comment: What if you don't use the starters and still want to use the auto configuration stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good question, and one that we have debated inconclusively in the Spring Boot engineering team, so there is no correct answer. Relevant points for discussion:

- spring-boot-autoconfigure started out as quite a small library (pre 1.0). It has grown now to the extent that its pom is kind of ridiculously long (and nearly everything is optional).
- Starters perform more than one function, in the sense that they can be used to activate bits of autoconfiguration, but also (and more importantly) 
  , they are an opinionated, curated set of dependencies that might (and usually does) go beyond the minimum needed to activate some autoconfiguration. This is basically Marten's point.
- Spring Boot .NEXT (1.3 at the point) will more than likely unbundle spring-boot-autoconfigure into multiple modules (e.g. there might be one for jetty, or maybe one for servlet containers, or something esle).

When the unbundling happens we might see some starters becoming obsolete (who knows at this point), but I suspect they will still exist. Spring Cloud has a lot of unbundled autoconfiguration, but still has starters, for instance.

For small third party libraries I see no reason why starters and autoconfiguration shouldn't be co-located. I think the only justification for allowing this thread on stackoverflow is if it can be re-worded to make the question more obviously about that.